# Scala: How to simplify nested pattern matching statements

Tags: scala, hive, udf

I am writing a Hive UDF in Scala (because I want to learn scala). To do this, I have to override three functions: `evaluate`, `initialize` and `getDisplayString`.

In the initialize function I have to:

- Receive an array of `ObjectInspector` and return an `ObjectInspector`
- Check if the array is null
- Check if the array has the correct size
- Check if the array contains the object of the correct type

To do this, I am using pattern matching and came up with the following function:

```
  override def initialize(genericInspectors: Array[ObjectInspector]): ObjectInspector = genericInspectors match {
    case null => throw new UDFArgumentException(functionNameString + ": ObjectInspector is null!")
    case _ if genericInspectors.length != 1 => throw new UDFArgumentException(functionNameString + ": requires exactly one argument.")
    case _ => {
      listInspector = genericInspectors(0) match {
        case concreteInspector: ListObjectInspector => concreteInspector
        case _ => throw new UDFArgumentException(functionNameString + ": requires an input array.")
     }
      PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.getPrimitiveWritableObjectInspector(listInspector.getListElementObjectInspector.asInstanceOf[PrimitiveObjectInspector].getPrimitiveCategory)
    }
  }
```

Nevertheless, I have the impression that the function could be made more legible and, in general, prettier since I don't like to have code with too many levels of indentation.

Is there an idiomatic Scala way to improve the code above?

Comment: 1) `initialize` currently takes an array of `ObjectInspector` (instead of `DeferredObject`. 2) What is `ListObjectInspector` to `ObjectInspector`? A subtype? 3) Are you open to throwing fewer exceptions and adopting a more functional style?

Comment: `case Array() | Array(_, _, _*)` could advantageously be substituted for `case _ if genericInspectors.length != 1`.

Comment: @Jubobs 1) Corrected :) 2) `ListObjectInspector` implements the interface `ObjectsInspector` 3) I definitely want to be more "functional" but the exceptions are the way to pass information to the user that's running the function in Hive

Comment: @Jubobs do you have an example of how to make the function more functional-like by removing the throwing of the exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typical for patterns to include other patterns. The type of `x` here is String.

```
scala> val xs: Array[Any] = Array("x")
xs: Array[Any] = Array(x)

scala> xs match {
     | case null => ???
     | case Array(x: String) => x
     | case _ => ???
     | }
res0: String = x
```

The idiom for "any number of args" is "sequence pattern", which matches arbitrary args:

```
scala> val xs: Array[Any] = Array("x")
xs: Array[Any] = Array(x)

scala> xs match { case Array(x: String) => x case Array(_*) => ??? }
res2: String = x

scala> val xs: Array[Any] = Array(42)
xs: Array[Any] = Array(42)

scala> xs match { case Array(x: String) => x case Array(_*) => ??? }
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:230)
  ... 32 elided

scala> Array("x","y") match { case Array(x: String) => x case Array(_*) => ??? }
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:230)
  ... 32 elided
```

This answer should not be construed as advocating matching your way back to type safety.